# add linkin print icon on to my page

Tags: php, facebook, plugins

I would like to add tiny (10x10) facebook, linkedin, print icons next to mysite's article title to that once the user clicks it will do the the task (ie. facebook: it will add the article title as news into that user's facebook)
How can this be done ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it is possible for you to use AddThis.
http://www.addthis.com

You can select what type of media the user can share your content on. Facebook and LinkedIn is some of the defaults.